# Random number and placement - I am missing one number

Tags: javascript, random, adobe-edge

I am working in Edge Animate.

I am trying to place symbols in 2 different places and when I generate them, I am always missing one symbols.

Also I would like to be able to place the first 3 numbers in their own container - if the number is 2 it should go in `location1[1]`, if the number is 8, it should be placed in `location1[7]`. I am not sure how I can accomplish that.

The numbers array contains the name of symbols with numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
`location1` is an array containing the name of the containers for each possible 3 numbers.

The rest of the containers will become droppables.

`location2` is an array containing the name of the container for the remaining numbers which will become draggables.

Here is my code:

```
var numbers = ['num1','num2','num3','num4','num5','num6','num7','num8','num9','num10'];
var location1 = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10'];    
var location2 = ['circle0','circle1','circle2','circle3','circle4','circle5','circle6','circle7','circle8','circle9'];


//randomize numbers
var placedNumbers = numbers.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});

// place the 3 first numbers on the top list.
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
sym.createChildSymbol(placedNumbers[i],location1[i]);
}
// place the rest of the numbers in the bottom list
for (j=3;j<11;j++){

sym.createChildSymbol(placedNumbers[j],location2[j]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the animation package, but this might point you in the right direction.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv372/2/) using divs as containers (each div id generated from the for loop).  This is the main bit:

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  $('#divOne').append('<div id = ' + location1[i] + '>' + placedNumbers[i] + '</div>');
}
// place the rest of the numbers in the bottom list
for (i=3;i<10;i++){
  $('#divTwo').append('<div id = ' + location2[i] + '>' + placedNumbers[i] + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is not quite right because the numbers in the first list need to go to their place location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is better but still not quite right. In the first list, i want the numbers to be placed in their respective div - there is 10 div to place numbers 1 to 10 - so the 3 numbers that are placed at the beginning need to be in the right place - for example number 2 would be in div 3 which is location1[2]. Does this make sense? However, the bottom numbers need to be random since the student will attempt to fill in the numbers in order.

Comment: I do not understand why but I still do not get the 10 numbers - so strange!